# The start up menu doesnt work in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

Every time there is an update, it somehow screws up the setting on my laptop.  Now I cannot see any of the Apps and the Start menu doesn't work

Firstly, please advise if it is absolutely necessary to do updates.

Would appreciate help.

Thanks

Comment: I think that updates on Windows are mandatory.

Comment: Support for Windows 8 has been dropped a long time ago. You should upgrade to 8.1 or 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for security reasons, it is important to do updates for any computer connected to the internet that does not use a read-only OS (e.g. kiosk running from DVD).

That said, there are third-party replacements for the Start Menu such as the free [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) and [its alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/classicshell/), as well as for the menu shortcut system, such as [Clavier+](http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php?sLang=en) to accommodate the many (often unwanted) changes caused by Windows Update. These third-party tools have the advantage of maintaining a consistent look-and-feel despite major changes in the underlying OS.